# Retrieve checked status of two buttons with same class for use in if statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple sets of radio buttons in the same page, all of which share the same data apart from each set's name.

For the sake of this question, let's say I have three buttons within each set, and that there are 2 sets (in reality there are many more of each).

HTML:

```
<input class="radio-1" name="set-1" type="radio">
<input class="radio-2" name="set-1" type="radio">
<input class="radio-3" name="set-1" type="radio">

<input class="radio-1" name="set-2" type="radio">
<input class="radio-2" name="set-2" type="radio">
<input class="radio-3" name="set-2" type="radio">
```

It's important for me to use the same class name and to not name them each a separate id, because there are so many that it would make coding the functions I will use them for an unbearably long and complex process.

In my JS, I want to be able to say: "if any (even if only one) of the radio buttons that share the 'radio-2' class name are checked, then proceed with function 1. Else, proceed with function 2."

This is what I have in my JS, but it's not working:

```
var radio2 = document.getElementsByClassName('radio-2');

if (radio2.checked) {

// Perform function 1

  } else {

// Perform function 2

  }
```

How would you get this working? I'm open to any sort of workaround.

Comment: Since you are selecting by class (i.e can be more than one), you need a loop to check them one-by-one.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the response Chris! How would you go about coding a loop?

Answer (score 1):

you could use JQuery for that:

```
// select all DOM elements of type 'input' with css class 'radio-2' that are checked!
if ($('input.radio-2 :checked').size() > 0) {
    //call function 1
} else {
    //call function 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the class with name selector

```
if ($('radio-2[name=set-2or anything] :checked').size() > 0) {
     //call function 1
} else {
     //call function 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, this worked for me:

```
if ($('input.radio-2').is(':checked')) {
  //call function 1
} else {
  //call function 2
}
```